# Python Selenium - Automate find location - select

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have a field on my webpage, where I enter the address, and it automatically looks up in back end with attached OpenMaps or GoogleMaps, and lists matched address.

How can I write an address, and also select the first one that pops up?

I tried the select class in selenium, and after a while I realized, it only works with a list. 
At present I can enter the address information, by id, but cannot select the first output.

Looking for the right class I should use in selenium.

The url is presently local host, so I could not post that. However here is the code snippet.

```
 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

vendor_storelocator = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('leaflet_find_address'))
    vendor_storeaddress ='//*[@id="leaflet_find_address"]'
    test_address = '123 Main street Minneapolis MN 55408'

    driver.find_element_by_xpath(vendor_storeaddress).send_keys('test_address')
    vendor_storelocator.select_by_index(1)
```

and the inspect code is as follows, for the whole field.

[image]

The image below is the image of the form. When an address is entered, it pop's up the suggestions. I need to click the top suggestion.

[image]

Comment: please add the code for what you tried on selenium , and how the DOM for what you want to select looks like

Comment: Maybe try adding a delay after ```driver.find_element_by_xpath(vendor_storeaddress).send_keys('test_address')```

Comment: I guess the problem is that you don't give your application any time to send the answer to your request before you try to select it. You can tell selenium to wait: [link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: It is telling me that I cannot use the select on the first line

Comment: Is Select a function or a class you defined somewhere else? or where does it come from? EDIT: I looked up the selenium Select class. Its not what you want it to be [Select](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select). You should just change the line to not use the Select and it should work.

Comment: Select is a class from selenium. The error exactly is select only works on element, and not on input

Comment: Okay I got it. The selenium Select class is indeed only for HTML select elements. I have no idea why you would use it here. I guess you got confused by its name, because you want to select an element. That's what find_element_by_id does for you. No need for the Select class!

Comment: Yes I tried that as well. find_element_by_id, and then I can do send_keys. However it shows me an output, that I need to click. I updated with an image.